# How to use .indexOf JS function with array? or Alternative?

Tags: javascript

Is there possibility of using `.indexOf` function with an array to search with? Like This:

```
var d = "Hello";
var s = new Array ("Heart", "David", "Foo", "Hello");
if( d.indexOf(s) != -1) {
  alert("Found Hello");
}
```

If I use above code then it does not alert anything. I checked console but **no errors**.

*I read somewhere that `.indexOf` function is for strings only not for array of string.*

*Is there alternative of `indexOf` in Javascript or `.indexOf` already provides what i want?*

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/UndfJ/)

Comment: It's `s.indexOf(d)` -- swap the variables around.

Comment: Also note that if you need to support older browsers, `Array.prototype.indexOf` may not be supported. There's a [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: thanks @Jon ! :D and also JamesAllardice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling the method on the object you wish to search not on the item which you wish to search for, `s.indexOf(d)` in your case

Answer (score 1):

There are `indexOf` functions both for [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). You applied it on the string, and checked whether the stringification of the array is contained in it - you get no error, but does not work. You have to do it the other way round to check whether the string is an item of the array:

```
s.indexOf(d) != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this problem is to use the hash map property of JavaScript objects:

```
var d = "Hello";
var s = {"Heart": 1, "David": 1, "Foo": 1, "Hello": 1};
if (s[d]) {
    alert("Found Hello");
}
```

Comment: There isn't a single array in this answer. (Unless you count strings as being arrays of characters)

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe not with the {} object notation, but JavaScript arrays are string hash maps: http://i.imgur.com/HZEqF.png

Comment: That returns true because you're declaring `arr` like `arr = []`, so as array.
`Array.isArray(s);` (`s` from your answer) returns `false`, though. Because it's an Object.

Comment: Yes, but an object in this case is the only way to express the same thing in a single statement.

Comment: Good job on replacing the word "arrays" with "objects". Now, technically, there is no _"hash map property of JavaScript objects"_, it would be more accurate to say that objects are hash maps. But that's nitpicking...